# How to pass variable from a servlet to a jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet (front-controller), which analyse the request, prepare some necessary data (model) and then should pass it to the jsp to be rendered.

How should I pass the data from servlet to jsp? (I hoped that it was possible to add new parameters to parameters map in the `request` object, but that map is unmodifiable).

I can add attributes to the `request` but I don't know how to retrieve them from the jsp.

All the data should be in the request scope. What's the correct way?

Comment: Here's a hello world: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info There are by the way a lot of dupes in "Related" section at the right column, which you should already have seen in top of your question while entering the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I can add attributes to the request but I don't know how to retrieve them from the jsp.*
You don't need to specifically 'retrieve' them, just referring them works

```
request.setAttribute("titleAttribute", "kittens are fuzzy");
```

and then

```
Title here: ${titleAttribute}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the request or the session scope for this.  Apart from the answer by Nikita Rybak, you can use

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("key","value");
```

And then use it in JSP using scriplet.

```
<%=session.getAttribute("key")%>
```

Note that in the example given by Nikita, Expression Language(EL) has been used(I am not sure if it's JSTL tags). You need to explicitly state that EL is not to be ignored by using the `isELIgnored` property.

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Comment: This is exactly the code-examples I needed to get me past this hump -- thanks!  +1